# Electric current streamlines in induction cooking vessel

Tags: solid-state-physics, applied-physics, computational-physics, induction

I am looking for a plot of the typical streamlines of the electric induced currents ("eddy currents") in a induction cooking vessel.

How can one theoretically predict the streamlines? How is it possible to measure the streamlines?

I was able to find a plot for the streamlines for a moving plate in a magnetic field in [Heald: Magnetic braking: Improved theory](http://ajp.aapt.org/resource/1/ajpias/v56/i6/p521_s1?isAuthorized=no)

[image]

and want something similar for the induction cooking vessel.

Just another question about the moving plate: Up to now I had in mind that eddy currents have to be closed, however in the picture above some lines are **not** closed. So, what's true and why?

Answer (score 1):

The shape of the induced [eddy currents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current) in induction cooking will depend on the shape of the fluctuating magnetic field and the shape of the cooking vessel.  Certainly there are commonalities though and I suspect the diagram you have is similar.  Also, in the case of induction cooking, the field is varying rather than the vessel moving and this will cause the shape of the current loops to vary too.

Regarding closed eddy currents, all current must form a loop.  The eddy currents are closed and you're just seeing a cropped diagram.  For example, here is a cropped magnetic field line diagram:

[image: Cropped image of magnetic field lines]

All magnetic field lines ether extend to infinity or form a loop.  In the case of a idealized perfect bar magnet, only the two lines normal to the N and S poles extend to infinity.  They just look open because the image is cropped.